# Add a period two characters from the end of each line

Tags: sed

What is the best way to add a period two characters from the end of each line in a txt file using sed? Other options are also welcomed.

```
199801_Track_1.1 xx 303
199801_Track_1.2 xx 264
199801_Track_1.3 xx 92
199801_Track_1.4 xx 61
199801_Track_1.5 xx 402
```

becomes

```
199801_Track_1.1 xx 3.03
199801_Track_1.2 xx 2.64
199801_Track_1.3 xx .92
199801_Track_1.4 xx .61
199801_Track_1.5 xx 4.02
```

I have 2500 lines in a text file and each line ends in either two or three random digits.  Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything? Your task looks quite too easy. What have gone wrong?

Comment: I guess easy for someone with more experience than I have, which isn't much.  I figured out how to delete nth characters at the end or from the beginning of a line, as well as replacing one instance of one word with another but to add a character in the middle (or towards the end) of a string, that I just couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
sed 's/..$/.&/' file
```

This substitutes the two characters at the end of the line, which is matched by `..$`, with a period and then the matched pattern, which is denoted by `&`.

Comment: Thanks bkmoney, that worked wonderfully. Extra thanks for the explanation.  I cant say i fully understand sed but I'm getting there :)

Comment: No problem. This is a good tutorial to get started on sed if you wanted to learn more http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: I also recommend the grymoire sed tutorial.  (The grymoire tutorial for awk is also excellent.)

Comment: @BBLocks just don't get caught up in what you CAN do with sed and instead focus on what you SHOULD do with sed and that way you'll save yourself about 10 years of pain before learning awk. All you need to know in sed is how to use s, g, and p (with -n), everything else became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. You do not need a book to learn sed, for awk get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks guys for the advice and tutorial... i've seen many reference to awk but have not used it... but I am looking into it presently.